# React native rendering flickers

Tags: javascript

The following is the example code.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  LayoutAnimation,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const _use = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}];

const _unuse = [{name: 'k'}, {name: 'l'}, {name: 'm'}];

const _WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const App = () => {
  const [Use, setUse] = useState(_use);
  const [UnUse, setUnUse] = useState(_unuse);

  const RenderUse = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          backgroundColor: 'black',
        }}>
        {Use.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Text
              key={item.name}
              style={{
                borderColor: '#333',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 2,
                width: '20%',
                marginRight: (index + 1) % 4 !== 0 ? 10 : 0,
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const RenderUnUse = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}>
        {UnUse.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 2,
                width: '20%',
                marginRight: (index + 1) % 4 !== 0 ? 10 : 0,
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                console.log(item);
                LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
                setUse([...Use, item]);
                setUnUse(UnUse.filter(i => i.name !== item.name));
              }}>
              <Text
                key={item.name}
                style={{
                  borderColor: '#333',
                  textAlign: 'center',
                }}>
                {item.name}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginTop: 20,
      }}>
      {RenderUse()}
      {/*<RenderUse />*/}
      <Text>UnUse</Text>
      {RenderUnUse()}
      {/*<RenderUnUse />*/}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When I turn on LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut(); to call RenderUnUse and RenderUse in component mode, when I click k l m, RenderUnUse will flash

```
    <View
      style={{
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginTop: 20,
      }}>
      <RenderUse />
      <Text>UnUse</Text>
      <RenderUnUse />
    </View>
```

But when I call as a function, it will not blink and display normally

```
    <View
      style={{
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginTop: 20,
      }}>
      {RenderUse()}
      <Text>UnUse</Text>
      {RenderUnUse()}
    </View>
```

I want to know why it doesn't blink when I call as a function, but it does blink when I call as a component